# Scale up or scale down report generated as pdf

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, page-size

I've created an A4 size report in *iReport* & I export it as PDF format without any problem. Now I need to resize (stretch) it to smaller (A5) or bigger (A3) size. I can change the page size but it does NOT stretch elements on the report & only changes printing view!
How can I scale up or down all elements of the report in pdf (or any other) format programmatically when exporting report?

Comment: Do you need to produce a A3 or A5 pdf from iReport or continue to produce A4 and then stretch it?

Comment: I've already an A4 report & now I just want to resize it

Comment: You can do that using itext / itextsharp and few lines of code.